# how do i programatically access a dropwizard asset?

Tags: dropwizard

I've added some static assets to dropwizard; i'd like to be able to programatically modify them occasionally (say, rename/copy the files, etc...)

does dropwizard provide a quick and easy way to get access to them? (can't seem to find it in any of the docs or while browsing through the libraries)

Answer (score 0):

By default your AssetBundle will access things under your resources. I.e. if you want to modify them in runtime it might be a bit tricky.

However, there is a plugin that allows you to map external assets:
https://github.com/bazaarvoice/dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle

Saved for last, I would like to ask why you would want to do this? It doesn't seem like a good idea. Wouldn't it be better to create more dynamic content?